# interpretation of simulation results : capacity with precoder

Tags: digital-communications, capacity

I am studying the concept of computation the capacity. I have early asked [about the difference between CSI unknown/ known to transmitter here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63661/meaning-channel-unknown-and-known-at-the-transmiiter/63663?noredirect=1#comment129400_63663).

In the [book about Matlab implementation OFDM system](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~giri/pdfs/EE6002/book-cho.pdf), the equation for capacity with CSI is known to the transmitter is given.
$$ C = \max  \log_2 \det (I_{N_R} + \frac{E_x}{N_T \cdot N_0} H \cdot  H^H) $$
I would like to rewrite the above equation for the case if the signal is precoded and have got :

$$ C = \max  \log_2 \det (I_{N_R} + \frac{E_x}{N_T \cdot N_0} H \cdot V \cdot V^H \cdot H^H) $$

I have simulated it in Matlab and got :
[image]

***dashed line - with precoder ;   line        - wihout precoder***

I see, as SNR increases, the precoder provides a larger improvement in capacity and also decrease the bit error rate (BER).

what conclusions can I make else?

Comment: You could try to work with `BER` instead of `SER`.

Comment: What am I looking at in this plot? Adding x-axis and y-axis labels would help

Comment: @Engineer It is BER vs SNR

Comment: Hmm..could you add some code snippets if they are relatively small? There are some weird things happening: (1) BER will be in the range 0-1, not 2-16, and (2) BER shouldn't be higher for a better SNR

Comment: @Engineer I have mistaken. In Figure Capacity vs SNR is given...

Comment: What is the question then? The capacity looks to be increasing like $\text{log}(1+x)$. If you're doubting your result then adding how you generated the plot to the question would be helpful